# Firefox displays weird encoding icons on websites like GitHub

Tags: linux, firefox, encoding, github

On Mozilla Firefox (on GNU/Linux) with default font and UTF-8 encoding, I am seeing some websites, such as GitHub, display weird characters across the page.

[image: Weird behavior]

Under a different browser, such as WebKit based, the site looks normal.

What is causing these icons or glyphs to appear when I view such sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a website viewed in Firefox looks like it's all jacked up but in other browsers it's okay then you may have switched off allowing the site to download and/or display a custom font.

This is usually the case if you are seeing gibberish like a small box with numbers and letters on top of each other on parts of the website where you would [expect to see custom icons](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/).

To fix this, go to

> Tools → Options → Content → Fonts & Colors → Advanced

Make sure the following has a check mark in the box:

> ☑ Allow characters to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above

OK, OK, and you will now see the font icons the site has set up.

Comment: Note: This also applies to Firefox' internal PDF viewer (pdf.js). If "Allow characters to choose their own fonts[...]" is disabled, most PDF files will look *very* weird, because all text will use the default font.